# How to use authentication for multiple tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

i have a different users in my app in separate tables but i need to make them all login from the same form then redirect them based on their role

Can it be done or not?

Comment: can you show what you have done so far

Comment: nothing yet
i don't know where to start

Comment: what you need is to study a little about laravel guard, you are going to separate those table using guards, try something, post where you've failed and someone out there will humbly assist.

Comment: also your question was can it be done? yes it can be done using guards

Comment: how to make guard select form all tables

Comment: https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel

Comment: not what i am looking for
i need (admin ( table) ,teacher ( table) ,student ( table) ) to login from the same form not using separate forms

Comment: thanx for helping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213283/discussion-between-emeka-okafor-and-mohammed).

Comment: @mohammed that's will may help you
https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-multi-authentication